# 5 V to 3.3 V buck with limited input current and large capacitor to cover current spikes?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, backup

We need to design a power supply for a 3.3 V WiFi-device. But there are quite some current spikes during WiFi startup. Using the design below there is a risk the 5 V (250 mA max) supply (not mine) will "fold back".

I thought of adding a large capacitor but am not sure how to do this. I found the Richtek RT8032 which seems to do what I need but it is eol. TI and Analog seem to have a lot but nothing exactly what I need.

[image]

Comment: Ask a question and it likely gets answered. Right now it is difficult to understand what is the question.

Comment: Capacitors work only for a short time. It looks as if you need to find out what the actual current requirements are, and to design a supply that is able to handle that.

Comment: Energy out < energy in. If you can't supply enough of it from your 5 V supply, you need to take it from somewhere else. Please measure current consumption over time and calculate how much energy you need to store in your capacitor. If more than ms of time, you may be better off with a battery.

Comment: Calculate the duration of the current spikes and then calculate a capacitance. As they get longer you'll end up with even higher capacitance. Higher capacitance is not always good i.e. it may lead to instability of the supply that you put the high capacitance across.

Comment: the question was for help with this design but that got deleted

Comment: there is enough energy on average but not in all instances, that is why i need the capacitor. the theoretical energy buffer comes to about 700uF. just adding a large capacitor is not going to work because of inrush currents. i tried with 2200uF, charged it up to 5v before connecting to the 5v supply - sort of works but is not practical. that is why i need current limiting on the input

Comment: It could work if the wifi connection is short and the power consumption is optimized. For example, static IP instead of DHCP queries, CPU freq reduced to 80MHz, etc. And big capacitors in the MCU side. I have an ESP32-C3 powered with an LDO-1700 of 250mA and it works fine, but it just sends a couple of sensor measures every 15 mins.